# Converter horas "hh:mm:ss" para minutos no formato int

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Tenho a seguinte função que calcula as horas `01:00`, retorna 60 minutos. 
 mas a coluna do `sql` armazena no formato time(0) `01:00:00`, 
O que da erro na minha função, não sei incrementar o código para calcular os segundos, e me retornar os 60 minutos inteiros.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_CONVHORA] (@Horas varchar(10))
RETURNS int
BEGIN
DECLARE @iMinutos INTEGER 
Select @iMinutos =
  (Convert(int, SubString(Convert(VarChar(10), @Horas), 1, 
  CharIndex(':', Convert(VarChar(10), @Horas)) - 1)) * 60) + (Convert(int, SubString(Convert(VarChar(10), @Horas), 
  CharIndex(':', Convert(VarChar(10), @Horas)) + 1, 
  Len(Convert(VarChar(10), @Horas)) -  CharIndex(':', Convert(VarChar(10), @Horas)))))
 RETURN @iMinutos
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que você está utilizando um tipo data para armazenar seus dados, você nem precisa de uma função para isso, basta usar o [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189794%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, 0, '20:10:10') AS diferenca_em_segundos
```

[Exemplo no *SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/6808)

**Sintaxe do `DATEDIFF`**

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

*datepart* - parte da data a ser retornada, no seu caso *second*.

*startdate* - a data inicial. Como você quer contar os segundos somente da hora, considere como zero.

*enddate* - a data final do intervalo. No seu caso a hora desejada.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, programo em sql e c# a 2 anos, apenas para uso próprio, e tem função que vejo e nem imagino para que serve, mas é exatamente isso que eu preciso.  Isso será um programa tipo o velho  e bom controle dos pais do Windows, que hoje virou uma bos..... quero bloquear meus filhos em determinados dias e horários, mas apenas os programas que eu acho que eles não devem se envolver demais.

Answer (score 0):

Substitua sua função por essa chamada para retornar as horas em minutos:

```
SELECT CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, '01:03:00')) AS INT)
```

Caso tenha a intensão de pegar a informação diretamente de uma tabela, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, NomeDaColuna)) AS INT) FROM NomeTabela
```

Você pode adaptar sua função com essa instrução de código também:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_CONVHORA(@Horas VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0,convert(varchar(10), @Horas, 108))) AS INT))
END
```

Boa sorte!